# Why aren't my custom classes appearing in the dropdown in Interface Builder?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I am using Interface Builder and Storyboards to build my app. I am trying to connect my source code to my `UIViewController` in Storyboard, but none of my classes show up in the Custom Class dropdown menu. This is occurring in Xcode 11 beta 2 and Xcode 11 beta 4.

I've tried some solutions [in this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386081/unable-to-see-custom-classes-in-interface-builder-drop-down), but they are not working. I've already done all of the following:

- Relaunched Xcode
- Deleted derived data
- Reinstalled Xcode
- Tried a different Storyboard
- Recreated the `UIViewController` file
- Made a new project (the problem even occurred there)
- Typing the `UIViewController` name into the dropdown menu text field

None of the solutions worked and I have made sure that I was connected a `UIViewController` to the Storyboard not something else like a `UIView`. This is occurring with all of my `UIViewControllers` and `UITableViewControllers`.

(I wish I could show an image but I do not have enough reputation...)

I expected the `UIViewController`s that I have created to appear in the custom class dropdown. I also surprised to find out that manually typing the view controller into the text field does not work. Instead, when I run the project, I just get this message in the console:

> Unknown class *ViewControllerName* in Interface Builder file.

Comment: Does your class inherit `UIViewController`?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, my class inherits `UIViewController`.

Comment: Is this a framework?

Comment: It may be too late for this, but do you know if things worked in Xcode10?

Comment: @dfd Just checked Xcode 10. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your classes aren't added to the project target. Try this:

1) Make sure your classes are added to the right target membership on the Inspectors Panel on the right:

[image]

2) Make sure the class inherits the View Controller type:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController
```

3) Reload xCode and check if the class is enabled:

[image]

Comment: I did not have "Inherit Module From Target Checked". Now it is working, however, the `UIViewController`s do not appear in the Custom Class dropdown still.

Comment: There is definitely something very wrong because now I can't use unwind segues. Any other issues that can be causing this?

Comment: Are you using view controller extensions? There are similar issues here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269030/3241041

Comment: I am using extensions in my view controller files but even when I remove them the problem still occurs. What else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and I've noticed the Class dropdown was showing classes from another project that I have opened in the background. After closing all the other projects, the drop down finally showing the correct list of classes from the project that I'm working on. Seems like an Xcode storyboard editor bug.